# What's the term for the leaves of a graph in the orbit of a function?

Tags: functions, terminology, group-actions

Suppose the orbit of a function $f:X\to X$ only surjects over $Y\subsetneq X$ then $X\setminus Y$ is not in the range of $f$.

These elements $X\setminus Y$ are the leaves of the graph of $f$'s orbit in $X$.

Is there a terminology for this set $X\setminus Y$ as a component of $f$'s orbit or action?

We have that $f$ surjects over $Y$ or may be an epimorphism but is there a phrase for the preimage of the orbit that is not in the image?

Comment: It’s not entirely clear to me what you’re asking, or what the setup is. You might want to give a bit more explanation to your question.

Comment: I'm not aware of a shorter name than "complement of the image".